# R strsplit function in a data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, split

I create a data frame which now I want to separate one new column by split the ":" in first column.

```
data frame:
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results:ASL|435  214.4421
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results:ASS1|445 2863.8055
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results:OTC|5009 0
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results:ASL|435  332.7522
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results:ASS1|445 3322.629
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results:OTC|5009 0

desired output:
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results  ASL|435 214.4421
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results  ASS1|445    2863.8055
unc.edu.0057f9f7-779b-4914-8290-abbad2a0d81e.2556919.rsem.genes.normalized_results  OTC|5009    0
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results  ASL|435 332.7522
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results  ASS1|445    3322.629
unc.edu.050c2191-b96c-41e7-abdb-e52cbe82f268.2456235.rsem.genes.normalized_results  OTC|5009    0
```

I have tried

```
strsplit(df$V1, split = "\\:")
```

but Error in strsplit(t$V1, split = "\:") : non-character argument come out. Thank you.

Comment: Ensure that `V1` column is of `character` class not a `factor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because we have a variable of class `factor`.  Convert it to `character` and it should work

```
lst <- strsplit(as.character(df$V1), split = ":", fixed = TRUE)
```

---

If we need to create two columns, one easy way is with `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(text = as.character(df$V1), sep=":", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Or using `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, V1, into = c("V1", "V2"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tidyr::separate(data = df, col = V1, into = c('a', 'b'), sep = ':')
```